# No "More" button in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a simple ViewController - subclass of UITabBarController which was used for Single View Application, in viewDidLoad I created 10 tabs. if in AppDelegate.swift method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Actually the screen does show only 4 tabs. If I manually create Navigation Controller and set rootView controller to my ViewController in "didFinishLaunching"

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: ViewController())
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

then I am able to see 4 tabs and "More" button which brings the rest of 6 tabs. I could not use in a real application "TabbedApplication" template as I need to dispatch a flow into a particular screen and then segue to a tabbed controller, where I was not able a tab. controller to show "More" option.
Any clues ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the 10 tabs?

Comment: Definitely, here is a link to the project:

Comment: Click enter too early :( 
https://app.box.com/s/1rarygh83u0ezhtfe2pt5u3sa1hqispz